# How to change the in text style of Figure references?

Tags: floats, cleveref

I have generated a figure using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{DTW/time_warp_ctgf_plot_interp}
    \caption{this is i figure.}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}

I now refer to the figure \cref{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I would like to know how I can tell Latex to use `Figure 1` instead of `fig. 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know how I can tell Latex to use "Figure 1" instead of "fig. 1".

You should specify the options `noabbrev` and `capitalize` (`capitalise` works too) when loading the `cleveref` package:

```
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
```

Oh, and please don't write `I now refer to the figure \cref{figure}`; instead, just write `I now refer to \cref{figure}`.